# Flutter GetX State Management on button click

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

Am fairly new to flutter using GetX. I have MainDrawer stateful widget which has two widgets for two accounts personal and business, in my HomePage() i have TextWidget displaying the name of the account selected..
i want to use controller or any feature of GetX to update the displayed name..
NoTE: i have a MainPage() that hold the drawer and bottom Navigation in which HomePage() is one of the pages

Comment: extend your drawer class with your controller `class AppDrawer extends GetView<YourController>` after that you can access your accounts name with `controller.accounts.nam`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [State Management](https://pub.dev/packages/get#state-management) section of the official GetX documentation. With a simple obs and obx you should be able to achieve what you describe.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I know its late to say this.. but thanks, and yes i had a look and now am just fluttering in happiness.